# <textarea> becomes uneditable on pasting content with <blockquote>

Tags: html, input, textarea, plaintext

I am using standard HTML . All I care about is new lines and plaintext. Textarea works great for me. Except, when pasting content that is embedded in . This makes the Textarea uneditable, unless I delete the last line of the blockquote. 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enf84xmj/1/

```
    <textarea 
  autoCapitalize='sentences' 
  cols='69'
  maxLength='1000'
  minLength='1'
  rows='1000'>
  “One of us can be dismissed. Two of us can be ignored. But together, we are a movement and we are unstoppable.”
- Cecile Richards, president of Planned Parenthood Federation of America & Planned Parenthood Action Fund
In a surreal time when our hard-fought reproductive rights are in real peril, it is imperative that all-of-us stand strong and stand together in their defense.

To help Planned Parenthood launch its new project, UNSTOPPABLE, our Bay Area filmmaker friend and fellow activist Tiffany Shlain made a powerful short film called “Unstoppable Manifesto.” Hear what Tiffany had to share about her own personal experience and motivation:

“I grew up hearing stories from my late father, who, as a young surgeon, would try to save women in the emergency room after they were unable to get a safe abortion and ended up trying to do it themselves. In my early twenties, long before I was ready to have children, or had started my career or even met Ken, I became pregnant. I was in no way ready to become a mother, and was so grateful to be able to get a safe abortion. But even though I had a place to go, I still, like so many women, had to make my way through a line of protestors shouting terrible things at me, making what was already so difficult, worse.
</textarea>
```

I am trying to avoid adding a WYSIWYG editor and doing it using just HTML. Is it not possible?

Comment: Is it because the length of text your pasted in `textarea` already reached the maximum length (1000) ?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. You told it to has a maxlength of 1000 and it has a maxlength of 1000. This has nothing to do with blockquote, just with having 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

As @chaska pointed out, the maxlength attribute was responsible for it and had nothing to do with the type of content being pasted